# Make NSTableView NOT edittable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

**OK, so here's my situation :**

- I've got an `NSTableView`.
- Its columns are bound to an `NSArrayController`.
- ... which in turn is bound to an `NSMutableArray`.

**However :**

- When the user click in any of the cells, he's allowed to edit their content.
- We DON'T want that.

How should I do it, so that no table cells are editable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your NSTableViewDelegate return NO for this method:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
```